# iOS fetch collections with sortDescriptor set to localIdentifier

Tags: ios, nssortdescriptor, photosframework, photokit

it seems that I can not get a fetch result sorted by localIdentifier. Here is the code:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "localIdentifier", ascending: true)
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
let albums = PHCollection.fetchTopLevelUserCollections(with: options)
print(albums.count)
```

I've got this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported sort descriptor in fetch options: (localIdentifier, ascending, compare:)'
```

However in Apple doc, localIdentifier can be used as key.

Answer (score 0):

Because the object [PHCollection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phcollection) does not have such a key "localIdentifier". Use key "localizedTitle", he is works

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "localizedTitle", ascending: true)
```